# Laravel many to many whereDoesntHave

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have this code here simplified.

```
Post::whereDoesntHave('tags', function($query){
     $query->whereIn(tags.id, $tagIds);
})
```

Lets say that `tagIds = [1,2,3]`
My goal is to retrieve only Posts that do not contain all of those tags.
ex. if post has tags 1,2,3 , then it shouldn't be retrieved, but if it has 1,2,3,4 then it should.Code above doesn't return correct result. Appreciate any help.

Comment: You'll probably have to do `$posts = Post::query(); foreach($tags as $tag) { $posts = $posts->whereDoesntHave('tags', function ($query) use ($tag) { return $query->where('tags.id', $tag); }) }`, then finally `$results = $posts->get();` If you want to omit _all_ tags, as opposed to _any_, I think you'll need multiple subqueries.

Comment: It must be:  `$query->whereIn('id', $tagIds);`

Comment: @TimLewis i tried that already , not working

Comment: @Pippo Doesn't make sense, why would that make any difference, it can even make that id ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you forgot to put array `$tagIds` to your query. I hope it works

```
Post::whereDoesntHave('tags', function ($query) use ($tagIds) {
     $query->whereIn('tags.id', $tagIds);
})
```

or

```
Post::whereHas('tags', function ($query) use ($tagIds) {
     $query->whereNotIn('tags.id', $tagIds);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The query that would accomplish the examples you give is:

```php
use App\Models\Post;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

$tagIds = [1, 2, 3];

Post::query()
    ->whereHas('tags', function (Builder $query) use ($tagIds): void {
        $query->whereKeyNot($tagIds);
    })
    ->get();
```

But consider that this query just gives you those posts that has at least one tag that is not in the array. So, by example, a post with zero tags will be returned.

If you don't want that behavior, we need to make it a little bit more complex:

```php
Post::query()
    ->whereHas('tags', function (Builder $query) use ($tagIds): void {
        $query->whereKeyNot($tagIds);
    })
    ->orWhereHas('tags', function (Builder $query) use ($tagIds): void {
        $query->whereKey($tagIds);
    }, operator: '<', count: count($tagIds))
    ->get();
```

This query gives you those posts that don't have exactly the tags in the array.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to check for the existence of each tag separately, and then combine these checks using the `orWhere`, so that a post is returned if it does not contain any of the specified tags.

```
$posts = Post::where(function ($query) use ($tagIds) {
   foreach ($tagIds as $tagId) {
       $query->orWhereDoesntHave('tags', function ($query) use ($tagId) {
           $query->where('id', $tagId);
       });
   }
})->get();
```